# Conﬁdence interval for a normal mean based on sample quantiles in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I don't know how to solve c&d.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stats.SE. Take the opportunity to take the [tour](
https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour), if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [how to ask](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and on [formatting help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and write down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers.

Answer (score 1):

$$
s_1 < \frac{M-\mu}{Q_3-Q_1} < s_2
$$
You only need to solve for $\mu,$ and to do that use the fact that what gets done last should get undone first. What was done with $\mu$ was first subtracting it from $M$ and then dividing the result by $Q_3-Q_1.$ Dividing was done last, so you undo it first, by multiplying all three terms by $Q_3-Q_1:$
$$
s_1(Q_3-Q_1) < M-\mu < s_2(Q_3-Q_1).
$$
Then:
$$
-s_2(Q_3-Q_1) < \mu-M < -s_1(Q_3-Q_1)
$$
(the order of the terms gets reversed when multiplying all three terms by $-1$).

Finally:
$$
M-s_2(Q_3-Q_1) < \mu < M- s_1(Q_3-Q_1).
$$

Then in part (d), plug in those numbers.